# Moving list items with attachments in Asset Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, metadata

For some reason, one of our teams chose to store list item attachments in the Asset Library of the SPO site, instead of the default location (hidden Attachments folder inside the list). Now, the list has over 5000 items and I am asked to move the items to another archive list with all their metadata.

Is there a way to move items between lists along with their attachments hosted in Sites Asset Library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API as below in workflow to get all attach files in a list item:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items(itemid)/AttachmentFiles.
```

And copy the files to relevant document library:

[Using SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow to copy file via REST on Office 365](http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/2/19/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-to-copy-file-via-res.html)